# Pass empty argument as array index

Tags: r, arrays, function

I have a function that takes user input for array indices and then performs a calculation. The index must be a string. Here is a snippet of the data attributes for context:

```
> attributes(data)
$dim
[1]  50 100 100

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
 [1] "0.001"             "0.613224489795918" "1.22544897959184"  "1.83767346938775"  "2.44989795918367"  "3.06212244897959" 
 [7] "3.67434693877551"  "4.28657142857143"  "4.89879591836735"  "5.51102040816327"  "6.12324489795918"  "6.7354693877551"  
[13] "7.34769387755102"  "7.95991836734694"  "8.57214285714286"  "9.18436734693877"  "9.79659183673469"  "10.4088163265306" 
[19] "11.0210408163265"  "11.6332653061224"  "12.2454897959184"  "12.8577142857143"  "13.4699387755102"  "14.0821632653061" 
[25] "14.694387755102"   "15.306612244898"   "15.9188367346939"  "16.5310612244898"  "17.1432857142857"  "17.7555102040816" 
[31] "18.3677346938776"  "18.9799591836735"  "19.5921836734694"  "20.2044081632653"  "20.8166326530612"  "21.4288571428571" 
[37] "22.0410816326531"  "22.653306122449"   "23.2655306122449"  "23.8777551020408"  "24.4899795918367"  "25.1022040816327" 
[43] "25.7144285714286"  "26.3266530612245"  "26.9388775510204"  "27.5511020408163"  "28.1633265306122"  "28.7755510204082" 
[49] "29.3877755102041"  "30"               

$dimnames[[2]]
  [1] "10"   "20"   "30"   "40"   "50"   "60"   "70"   "80"   "90"   "100"  "110"  "120"  "130"  "140"  "150"  "160"  "170"  "180" 
 [19] "190"  "200"  "210"  "220"  "230"  "240"  "250"  "260"  "270"  "280"  "290"  "300"  "310"  "320"  "330"  "340"  "350"  "360" 
 [37] "370"  "380"  "390"  "400"  "410"  "420"  "430"  "440"  "450"  "460"  "470"  "480"  "490"  "500"  "510"  "520"  "530"  "540" 
 [55] "550"  "560"  "570"  "580"  "590"  "600"  "610"  "620"  "630"  "640"  "650"  "660"  "670"  "680"  "690"  "700"  "710"  "720" 
 [73] "730"  "740"  "750"  "760"  "770"  "780"  "790"  "800"  "810"  "820"  "830"  "840"  "850"  "860"  "870"  "880"  "890"  "900" 
 [91] "910"  "920"  "930"  "940"  "950"  "960"  "970"  "980"  "990"  "1000"

$dimnames[[3]]
  [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21" 
 [22] "22"  "23"  "24"  "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "32"  "33"  "34"  "35"  "36"  "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "41"  "42" 
 [43] "43"  "44"  "45"  "46"  "47"  "48"  "49"  "50"  "51"  "52"  "53"  "54"  "55"  "56"  "57"  "58"  "59"  "60"  "61"  "62"  "63" 
 [64] "64"  "65"  "66"  "67"  "68"  "69"  "70"  "71"  "72"  "73"  "74"  "75"  "76"  "77"  "78"  "79"  "80"  "81"  "82"  "83"  "84" 
 [85] "85"  "86"  "87"  "88"  "89"  "90"  "91"  "92"  "93"  "94"  "95"  "96"  "97"  "98"  "99"  "100"
```

I want to have something like this:

```
myfun <- function(index){
    apply(X=data[,index,], MARGIN = c(1,2),FUN =  mean)
}
```

However, if a user wants to select the entire data set, we need to have `data[,,]`. However, I am not sure how to achieve this as you cannot pass an empty argument to a function. How can I represent the empty spot between the commas as a function argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667872/passing-empty-index-in-r You could just call `myfun()` or `myfun(TRUE)`. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904827/the-representation-of-an-empty-argument-in-a-call/20906150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `missing`, so that a missing index implies "select all", which I assume means that the user would just want the grand mean.

```r
myfun <- function(index)
{
  if(missing(index)) mean(data) else apply(data[, index, ], 1:2, mean)
}
```